# What is the p.d.f of $Z$?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, density-function

Let $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}\sin x \;  (0<x<\pi )$ be the p.d.f of $X$ and $g(x)=\begin{cases}
x & \text{ if } x<\frac{\pi }{3} \\ 
\frac{\pi }{9} & \text{ if } x\geqslant \frac{\pi }{3}
\end{cases}$
and $Z=g(X)$. What is the p.d.f. of $Z$?  Since $g$ is not injective on $x\geq \frac{\pi }{3}$, I struggle with this problem. please help me..

Comment: Technically there is no pdf since distribution of $Z$ is not absolutely continuous. Work with the cdf instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the range $(0<X<\frac{\pi}{3})$ the density is the same $f_X$. When $X\geq \frac{\pi}{3}$ the rv is discrete, and in the point $Z=\frac{\pi}{9}$ the rv cumulates a positive probability mass...

Thus the requested "mixed" pdf is

$$ f_Z(z) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{sin (z)}{2},  & \text{if $0<z<\frac{\pi}{9} \cup \frac{\pi}{9}<z<\frac{\pi}{3}  $ } \\
\frac{3}{4}, & \text{if $z=\frac{\pi}{9}$}\\
0, & \text{elsewhere}
\end{cases}$$